# How to set Image fix XY in ImageView without stratch Using Universal Image Loader?

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

When i am uisng image to set image it will stretch, My image size so large then why its stretch, when i am  uisng fit to xy it also stretch,How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think your image is stretched because your ImageView and your image have different aspect ratio. FitXY means to use the aspect ration of your ImageView, so your image will be stretched due to it has a different aspect ratio.

You can solve your problem by giving the same aspect ratio to your ImageView as your image. Or, you can use centerCrop instead of fitXY, this won't stretch your image but will show only part of your image if it has the different aspect ratio with your ImageView.

Comment: i do't want to crop image need to show fullview of image

Comment: @AmitPrajapati You can solve your problem by giving the same aspect ratio to your ImageView as your image. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem, in you xml image view put :

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

and ofcouse remove :

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```